# MKMapView ignoring Safe Area on iOS 11 and iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, safearealayoutguide

I'm trying to migrate a app to iOS 11 and for days I'm stuck with one ugly UI bug after the other. This time: MKMapView. I have a bunch of buttons which I pinned to the Safe Area Layout Guides and everything is working fine - except the MKMapView.

It completely ignores the Safe Area and therefore the compass and legal buttons are hidden under bars or my own UI elements. To verify, I created a new project with only one plain UIViewController. Then I added a MKMapView and configured custom "additionalSafeAreaInsets" which are indeed completely ignored.

The worse is probably that even with just the MKMapView, the legal label looks horribly wrong on iPhone X.

**Question**: is there any way I can inset the legal label and the compass to not get hidden by custom views?

[image]

Comment: take mapview inside uiview then ?

Comment: This seems to have stopped working from iOS 11.1. I have tried all solutions I have found, but can't get it to work either. I have also seen a radar on this, so I guess it's an iOS bug that will be fixed.

Comment: are you using constraints and auto layout?

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to set `additionalSafeAreaInsets` of the view controller that contains the `MKMapView`. Doing so will allow you to adjust both the compass and "Legal" label as needed to accommodate for custom views on top of the map.

Comment: interesting, @dbart, where did you get that info?

Comment: Safe area insets are used to adjusts content offset inside scroll views (think `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`). An `MKMapView` is just a more complex scroll view that uses these insets to align floating content like "Legal" label and compass.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution worked for me

1. Disable compass in the MapView
2. Create a new Compass button manually and simply put it wherever you like it

Here is an example

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView! {
    didSet {
        let userTrackingButton = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: mapView)
        userTrackingButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        userTrackingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let compassButton = MKCompassButton(mapView: mapView)
        compassButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150)
        compassButton.compassVisibility = .adaptive

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
        mapView.addSubview(userTrackingButton)
        mapView.addSubview(compassButton)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this one is the most correct since iOS11.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into this for one of my own projects, looks like interface builder has a solution for this:

[image: On the map view, select "Preserve Superview Margins" and "Safe area relative Margins"]

On the map view, select "Preserve Superview Margins" and "Safe area relative Margins" and the legal + compass will be positioned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this issue is to use the `directionalLayoutMargins` property of UIView available in iOS 11.0+. This lets you specify the margins of a view before the content of any subviews (in this case the Legal notes) is drawn.

`mapView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 25, 0);`

Comment: Anyone else ever find themselves looking for the solution to a problem, only to find they've already recently solved it, but somehow completely forgotten this fact. :-/

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 13.2, iOS 15.4,select the view controller in Interface Builder and open the Attributes Inspector. In the section "Extend Edges", clear "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars" check boxes.